# Java heap space outOfMemoryError

Tags: java, parameters, runtime, heap-memory

To avoid the `java.lang.outOfMemoryError` I went to Control Panel-->Java-->Java-->View and set the runtime parameters. But it produces no change.

It is a simple program which I'm running via the command prompt. Initially I ran the code using `java -Xmx1024m PercolExp(class_name)` and it ran. But when I change java runtime parameters settings in the Java control panel and run the code by simply typing `java PercolExp` it doesn't take the heap size parameter into account.

Comment: You need to provide more info if you want any help.

Comment: You need to give more information: how do you launch your application? What parameter did you change?

Comment: Why do you think it produces no change? Provide more details about your program, the way you launch it etc.

Comment: My crystal ball tels me you are not using eclipse, but then it gets kinda fuzzy...care to elaborate?

Comment: The Windows Control Panel.
And yes,its not an application,just a simple program,which im running via command prompt.
initially i ran the code using java -Xmx1024m PercolExp(class_name)
And it ran.

But when i change java runtime parameters settings in java control panel and run the code by simply typing ''java PercolExp" it doesnt run.

Comment: @SathvikShetty I have edited your question to reflect that additional information.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed now that there is additional information about the issue.

Comment: @SathvikShetty When asking a question, try to be as specific as you can and include all the relevant information (like you did in the comments). If you don't, most people will not understand what you are asking for and close the question before you can say wait!

Answer (score 1):

The Control panel you've found is (I think) [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html#java).  If you read the page I linked you, you will find that it is the control panel for the Java plugin used by your web browser.  It only affects the embedded JVM that is used to run applets in web pages.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Control Panel controls the settings of the Java Runtime Environment for applets and Java Web Start applications. If you run your application from the command line (`java AppName`) those parameters won't be taken into account: you will need to specify them  manually every time.